# Functions of Independent Random Variables and Correlation

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, correlation

This may be a basic question, but let us say we have $s_1 \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$ and $s_2 \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$ where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are independent. Then consider functions $v_s(s_1,s_2)=s_1+\alpha s_2$ and $v_b(s_1,s_2) = s_2 + \beta s_1$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real valued scalars. My question is, does this imply $v_s$ and $v_b$ are correlated? My intuition tells me this must be so, however I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Do you know how to compute covariance and correlation ?

Comment: Yes of course. Let me rephrase my question though: is it still possible for $v_s$ and $v_b$ to be independent? Or does the above condition necessarily imply they are correlated.

Comment: Well, if $v_s$ and $v_b$ are independent, they'll have zero covariance. Can you compute their covariance and see (depending on $\alpha$ and $\beta$) whether it's zero ?